# Handling Special Characters in a Splunk Scripted Input

Tags: splunk

I've set up some python scripted inputs which work great for numerical values, but I'm having trouble when dealing with special characters.

The output of my script looks like:

```
fieldname1="60", fieldname2="abc", ...
```

When I start dealing with text input that may contain special characters, I might have fields like:

```
fieldname3=""\", fieldname4="<3", fieldname5=""8===D"
```

What is the best way to handle special characters, including quoted, commas, and equals signs?

Answer (score 0):

Depends 
What's the source of those special characters? 
You'll surely find an python module which will help you with that specific data
Recently had to clean html flags from a Sharepoint list in the customer engagement used the HTMLParser module
So you'd need to tell us more about your data